# sorting a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python

While working on a problem from Google Python class, I formulated following result by using 2-3 examples from Stack overflow-

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    return [b for a,b in sorted((tup[1], tup) for tup in tuples)]

print sort_last([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)])
```

I learned List comprehension yesterday, so know a little about list comprehension but I am confused how this solution is working overall. Please help me to understand this (2nd line in function).

Comment: will you add a link to the 'Google Python class'?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/?csw=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pattern is called decorate-sort-undecorate.

1. You turn each `(1, 3)` into `(3, (1, 3))`, wrapping each `tuple` in a new tuple, with the item you want to sort by first.
2. You sort, with the outer `tuple` ensuring that the second item in the original `tuple` is sorted on first.
3. You go back from `(3, (1, 3))` to `(1, 3)` while maintaining the order of the list.

In Python, explicitly decorating is almost always unnecessary. Instead, use the [`key` argument of `sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda tup: tup[1]) # or key=operator.itemgetter(1)
```

Or, if you want to sort on the reversed version of the `tuple`, no matter its length:

```
sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda tup: tup[::-1]) 
                              # or key=operator.itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear now, can you please tell me something about lambda (I know I can find about it on stack overflow, but want to know about your use of lambda here)

Comment: @Varun `lambda` just lets you declare a function inside an expression. It's the same as `def first_item(tup): return tup[1]` outside the function call, then `key = first_item` in the function call. See [Lambda Forms](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) in the Python Tutorial.

Comment: "That pattern is called decorate-sort-undecorate" .. never knew it has a name

Answer (score 3):

Lets break it down:

In : `[(tup[1],tup) for tup in tuples]`

Out: `[(3, (1, 3)), (2, (3, 2)), (1, (2, 1))]`

So we just created new tuple where its first value is the last value of inner tuple - this way it is sorted by the 2nd value of each tuple in 'tuples'.

Now we sort the returned list:

In: `sorted([(3, (1, 3)), (2, (3, 2)), (1, (2, 1))])`

Out: `[(1, (2, 1)), (2, (3, 2)), (3, (1, 3))]`

So we now have our list sorted by its 2nd value of each tuple. All that is remain is to extract the original tuple, and this is done by taking only b from the for loop.

The list comprehension iterates the given list (`sorted([...]` in this case) and returns the extracted values by order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nicely explained.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works by creating a new list with the element at index `1` followed by the original tuple for each tuple in the list. Eg. `(3,(1,3))` for the first element. The sorted function sorts by each element starting from index `0` so the list is sorted by the second item. The function then goes through each item in the new list, and returns the orignal tuples.

Another way of doing this is by using the `key` parameter in the sorted function which sorts based on the value of the `key`. In this case you want the `key` to be the item in each tuple at index `1`.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)],key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: It does _not_ reverse each tuple in the list. It wraps each tuple in another tuple.

Comment: Oh right i missed that, i thought it was tup[1],tup[0] but now that i looked back on it i see i have misread it, i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer to the accepted answer.. + here is an example for better visualization,

`key` is a function that will be called to transform the collection's items for comparison.. like `compareTo` method in Java.

The parameter passed to key must be something that is callable. Here, the use of `lambda` creates an anonymous function (which is a callable).
The syntax of lambda is the word lambda followed by a iterable name then a single block of code.

Below example, we are sorting a list of tuple that holds the info abt time of certain event and actor name.

We are sorting this list by time of event occurrence - which is the 0th element of a tuple.

*Shout out for the Ready Player One fans!* =)

```
>>> gunters = [('2044-04-05', 'parzival'), ('2044-04-07', 'aech'), ('2044-04-06', 'art3mis')]
>>> gunters.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
>>> print gunters
[('2044-04-05', 'parzival'), ('2044-04-06', 'art3mis'), ('2044-04-07', 'aech')]
```

Note - `s.sort([cmp[, key[, reverse]]])`  sorts the items of s in place